# React router componentDidMount not executing after switching route

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm creating a react web application using react-router to navigate between the pages. Some of these pages depend on componentDidMount running when you navigate to the page. However, it seems this doesn't run unless I refresh the page which seems very counter-intuitive to users.

Is there a way to force componentDidMount to run when the render method completes perhaps.

Sorry if this is seen as a duplicate question but nothing I've seen has helped me understand how to solve this issue.

```
componentDidMount = async () => {
    //initialize web3
    const web3 = await getWeb3();

    // get contract address
    const ethAddress = await storehash.options.address
    this.setState({ethAddress})

    //set account for Blockchain network
    this.setState({account: await web3.eth.getAccounts()})
    }
```

Comment: Componentdidmount runs only one time, when the component is rendered.
you can try using other lifecycles.

Comment: Also if you are doing the same initialization on multiple components, you could move that into the parent and pass via props or move the logic to a [Higher-Order-Component](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html)

Comment: the event you're looking for i guess is `componentWillReceiveProps` .. this will be called every time a component receives a new prop, and needs to be re-rendered

Comment: I'm not sending any props to this new page though, I just want a way to run some code when that new route loads

Comment: you are navigating to address that match the same `Route` but has different params, right?

Comment: did you fix this ? can you post the answer ?

Comment: You can use **componentWillReceiveProps**  for that

Comment: Hey @skyboyer
I had the same problem that the route was not changing but the different params.

And using `componentDidUpdate`  I was able to solve it.



```

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    // Check if  user id has changed
    if (prevProps.params.id !== this.props.params.id) {
      const { params, fetchTransactionsFromTheUser, fetchUser, onUserFetch } = this.props
      const newUserId = params.id
      fetchUser(newUserId).then(this.onUserFetch)
      fetchTransactionsFromTheUser({
        newUserId,
      })
    }
  }

Answer (score 2):

**tl;dr - Only Components rendered by Route (and their children) will re-render on a route change.**

I'm going to make a few assumptions. One is that the `componentDidMount` you're trying to use is on a component that is **not** a child of one of your Route components.

The second assumption I'll make is that you don't need to run when *that* component mounts, but when one of the new routes' components mounts.

The `componentDidMount` function in the Component that's being rendered by the Route is probably where you need to be. However, if you need to update something in this component's state when one of its children mounts, that won't help. However you can go about this a couple different ways.

**Quick and Dirty** *Don't get in the habit of doing this*

If you're just testing something, a quick and dirty method is to use a route's `render` property instead of `component`.

So for example, if your route looks like this:

```
<Route path="/some-route" component={NewComponent} />
```

You could change this (again... only for a quick test, not recommended to have this in any production code!)

```
<Route path="/some-route" render={(props) => {
    //do your console log or temporary testing stuff here
    return <NewComponent ...props />
}} />
```

**Pass down a function, that will pass up vars from the child**

A less dirty way, and assuming you want the code to have access to something on this parent component, would be to pass down a function to the component. Again, you'd have to use `render` for this:

```
someFunction = (passedVar) => {
    // do something with passedVar, which you'll pass from the new component
}

// ... then in the Router...

<Route path="/some-route" render={(props) => <NewComponent ...props onRouteLoaded={this.someFunction} />}} />
```

Then you'd have a function (`this.props.onRouteLoaded(...)`) that you can run on the `componentDidMount` of the `NewComponent` - NOT on this parent component. This will allow you to pass vars up to the parent component if you need to access that component's state, props etc.

**Recommended if you need to do that**

A much cleaner way to do it, would be to use Redux state to pass values around, but (completely respectfully) get your head around React lifecycles before you breach Redux (but you SHOULD breach Redux!)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle method to compare `previous props` with `current props` and rerun the logic again; like

```
      constructor(props) {
          super(props);
          this.componentLogic = this.componentLogic.bind(this);
      }

      componentLogic() {
        // fetch something or some other business logic
      }
    
      componentDidMount() {
        this.componentLogic();
      }
    
      componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
        // Typical usage (don't forget to compare props):
        if (
          this.props.reactRouterDom.params.slug !==
          prevProps.reactRouterDom.params.slug
        ) {
          this.componentLogic();
        }
      }
```

Here I am passing route slug as prop via `Higher Order Component(HOC)`, and tracking change in route via `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle.